Highcharts download in my application is not the same as what is in JSFiddler tool using the same JSON output
I have a JSON output that I call using Highcharts.Chart().  When I choose Download PNG from my download options, the resulting PNG file shows the chart correctly but text for each option of the legend ends up overlapping the other options.
I have put the JSON that comes from my application into JSFiddler.net and run the Download PNG option and the downloaded PNG shows as expected with no issues with my legend and footer.
I am including my JSON that I put into JSFiddler.net
Here is the Javascript section
const chartOptions = {
  chart: {
    height: 370,
    width: null,
    renderTo: "chartbody_1",
    type: "column",
    alignTicks: true,
  },
  title: { text: "Rapid Report" },
  credits: { enabled: false },
  plotOptions: {
    column: { stacking: "normal", minPointLength: 3 },
    line: {
      minPointLength: 3,
      dataLabels: { enabled: true },
      enableMouseTracking: false,
    },
    pie: {
      innerSize: 100,
      depth: 45,
      allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: "pointer",
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: "{point.name}: {point.percentage:.1f} %",
        style: { color: "black" },
      },
    },
  },
  lang: { downloadTitle: "Download Chart" },
  tooltip: {},
  xAxis: {
    labels: { rotation: -45 },
    categories: ["Jul/Aug", "Jul/Aug", "Jul/Aug"],
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: "Paid Subscriptions - Print",
      data: [22163072],
      dateComment: ["Last Updated: Aug 07 2024"],
    },
    {
      name: "Verified Subscriptions - Print",
      data: [36301],
      dateComment: ["Last Updated: Aug 07 2024"],
    },
    {
      name: "Ratebase",
      data: [21500000],
      dateComment: ["Last Updated: Aug 07 2024"],
      type: "spline",
      yAxis: 0,
    },
  ],
  yAxis: [
    { title: { text: "" }, min: 0, style: { color: "#2caffe" } },
    { title: { text: "" }, min: 0, style: { color: "#544fc5" } },
    {
      title: { text: "" },
      min: 0,
      style: { color: "#00e272" },
      opposite: true,
    },
  ],
  subtitle: {
    text: "Source: Alliance for Audited Media.  Reporting Period: ending 31 Dec, 2024",
    floating: false,
    crop: false,
    align: "left",
    x: 10,
    verticalAlign: "bottom",
    y: 20,
    style: { color: "black" },
  },
  exporting: {
  scale: 1,
  },
}

Highcharts.chart("container", chartOptions)

Here is the HTML Section
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>

My application uses code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js and https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js so I'm assuming it's not an issue with the Javascript files.
Here are the download PNG files
Downloaded PNG from JSFiddler
Downloaded PNG from my application
You can see the legend text in the image from my application overwrites the other legend text entries.
If anyone has any ideas I'd greatly appreciate it.
Thanks!

It seems like there are scaling discrepancies, have you tried to modify this option in your application? Also, for .NET usage there is reccommended Highcharts .NET Integration, do you use it?

If you mean to modify the JSON...it is the exact JSON that comes from my application.  I have changed the values of sourceWidth and sourceHeight, I have changed Scale.  All of the changes I have made result in the issue pictured with the legend text overwriting itself.  Currently we are not using .Net integration.

What do you mean the "Downloaded PNG from my application"? How does your application look like? How do you export the chart? How do you call the exporting process? Which version of Highcharts & the Export Server are you using? Please share more details about the process to get to the failed image.
